# Way to do 'netsend' between a windows and ubuntu computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, netsend

Windows has the ability to send a message so that it pops up on another windows computer that is on the same network using 'netsend'. Is there a way to do something similar between a WindowsXP computer, and a computer running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only done this once, I installed Linpopup which is basically a winpopup clone for Linux that can recieve/send messages over the net send/winpopup protocol.

[There is a guide to installing it here.](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/unofficial_ubuntu_starter_guide/index_022.html)

[Linpopup official page](http://www.littleigloo.org/software_002.php3) -

## LinPopUp

A Linux Enhanced port of Winpopup.

LinPopUp is a Xwindow graphical port of Winpopup, running over Samba. It permits to communicate with a windows computer that runs Winpopup, sending or receiving message. ( It also provides an alternative way to communicate between Linux computers that run Samba ). Note that LinPopUp is not only a port, as it includes several enhanced features like :

- Doesn't need to always run :
    If you close it, it will continue to receive all messages that are send to you. You can even quit Xwindow, and still receive messages. In fact, the only way to miss a message that was sent to you is to have your computer turned off.
- Full message base management :
    Messages are kept from session to session. You will always retrieve a message that was sent to you, ... if you have not deleted it.
- Can be run minimised :
    It will raise automatically each time a new message arrives.
- And many others features :
    Full message editor capabilities - Clipboard past & cut - All the docs you need - Easy installation - ...

[image]

Comment: They list copy/paste and ability to run minimized as "enhanced features"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [LinWinTalk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gladenetsend/). You'll need to have Samba installed as well.

[image]